# ¿Cómo generar los valores de un api según la fecha modificando la URL?

Tags: javascript, html5, json, google-chrome

¡Hola! mi profesor me dio un API('http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/api/v1/expenses') para que listara los gastos(item.amount) según la fecha que sea seleccionada. En el código (.js) que desarrolle cree un scroll para listar las fechas. El profesor me dice que la consulta no debo hacerla sobre los datos del JSON, sino desde la URL, debo modificar la URL para sacar los datos. El me dio este ejemplo : mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/expenses cada vez que escojo una fecha para que genere los datos que viera como se modifica la URL. Según solo es cambiar la URL, la URL es un STRING. Y si tenía dudas mirara en network de Chrome pero sinceramente no he dado con la solución, les agradecería grandemente si alguien puede ayudarme.

Este es el codigo (.jS) que hice para scroll:

```
function createNode(element) {
return document.createElement(element);
}

function append(parent, el) {
return parent.appendChild(el);
}

const fecha = document.getElementById('list');
const url = 'http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/api/v1/expenses';

fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
let expenses = data.expenses;
return expenses.map(function(item) {

function loadMore() {
let = option = createNode('option'),
  spanDate = createNode('span');

spanDate.innerHTML = `${item.date}`;

append(option, spanDate);
append(fecha, option);
}

fecha.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
if (fecha.scrollTop) {
loadMore();
}
});

loadMore();

});
});
```

Y este es el código html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">   
<h1>Gastos</h1>
<select id="list" class="custom-select">
<option>Fecha</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Gastos</h1>
    <select id="list" class="custom-select">
       <option>Fecha</option>
    </select>

    <br><br>

    <div id="respuesta">

    </div>

</body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    </script>
```

Js:

```
function append(parent, el) {
return parent.appendChild(el);
};

function createNode(element) {
return document.createElement(element);
};

const fecha = document.getElementById('list');
const pagos = document.getElementById('resultado');
const url = 'http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/api/v1/expenses';

$("#list").change(function() {
let suma = "";
expenses.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.date == $("#list").val()) {
        suma += `<b>Valor:</b> $ ${item.amount}`;
    }
});
document.getElementById('respuesta').innerHTML = ""
.innerHTML =  `${suma}`

});

let expenses = [];
fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
expenses = data.expenses;
return expenses.map(function(item) {
    function loadMore() {
        let option = createNode('option'),
        spanDate = createNode('span');
        spanDate.innerHTML = `${item.date}`;

        append(option, spanDate);
        append(fecha, option);
    }

    fecha.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        if (fecha.scrollTop) {
            loadMore();
        };
    });

    loadMore();
  });
});
```

Comment: Si claro, pero lo que necesito es listar los gastos según fecha seleccionada. ¿tienes alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: El problema es que segun veo no te arroja datos ordenados por fecha es decir.. en la primer consulta te puede traer datos de hoy como de hace 3 meses.. mm pues supongo que tienes que hacerle un pull a las paginas hasta que te deje de arrojar datos. es lo único que puedes hacer.

Comment: Una vez que tengas todos los datos consolidados en un array, pues podras hacer la busqueda con respecto a las fechas que se seleccionen.

Comment: Sé que se puede hacer de esa forma, pero la consulta no debo hacerla sobre los datos del JSON, sino desde la URL, debo modificar la URL para sacar los datos.

Comment: La modificas aumentando el numero de pagina. la url no te esta pidiendo de parametro fechas.. la pagina te pide de parametros el numero de la pagina.. En un metodo GET los parametros vienen despues del caracter "?", es decir que el parametro se llama "page" y ahi es donde asignas el valor. en codigo quedaria mas o menos asi:

Comment: Edite la respuesta: me falto decir que estoy haciendo las peticiones con jquery por lo cual tendrias que integrarlo.

Comment: Como resultado en la consola me saca todo el Array/Object.. Que condición puedo hacer para que arroje los gastos según la fecha, disculpa sino te entiendo es que soy nueva en esto.

Comment: La funcion CreateNode de tu codigo.. me la podras proporcionar? para ver que es lo que llevas.

Comment: Si claro! no me di cuenta que la había omitido en el código... ya lo edite, verifica :)

Comment: Le Agregue esta etiqueta label para mostrar la respuesta:             `<label id="respuesta">prueba</label>` Ademas agregue este evento al select: `$("#list").change(function(data) {
                var suma = 0;
                expenses.forEach(function(item) {
                    if (item.date == $("#list").val()) {
                        suma += item.amount;
                    }
                });
                $("#respuesta").text(suma);
            });`

Comment: Entiendo todo pero como quedaría el código completo junto al mio? pdta: te mereces 100 estrella por toda esa paciencia. En serio gracias.

Comment: Si. solo agrega el label a tu html, asi como el codigo en tu archivo .js

Comment: Leo, podrías colocar el código completo como respuesta, para aceptarla y así a futuro otros compañeros que tenga una pregunta similar puedan ver como es la solución.

Comment: Listo. Solo estoy mostrando la sumatoria de el ammount. El evento scroll al parecer no esta funcionando, tienes el css de ese select?

Comment: Para que el evento loadMore funcione agregale un size al select en el html ejemplo: `<select id="list" class="custom-select" size="4">`

Comment: solo le tenia un css: select#selectionDate{ width: 20%; }

Comment: la funcion $("#list").change(function(data)  esta declarada pero no se lee su valor creo que por eso genera las fechas

Comment: El ID (list) del elemento  SELECT le faltaba las comillas, por esta razón no se generaba las fechas. Gracias por colaboración Leo